# Remote roster management with Smack

Tags: xmpp, openfire, smack, asmack

Using smack can I change another user's roster with enough privileges? 
For example: I log in as admin of the XMPP server using smack. Given the right privileges, can I change any other user's roster and add or edit items in it?

If yes, how do I do it in Smack and what are the privileges?
Is remote roster management(XEP-0321) designed for this ? Does smack support this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is remote roster management(XEP-0321) designed for this?

No, see [Remote roster management with Smack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26873529/remote-roster-management-with-smack#comment42911096_26873996)

> Does Smack support this?

No, Smack does not provide support for XEP-321 (yet). But it's possible to write an extension for Smack that adds support for it.

Comment: Any pointers? I would like to create the extention and also contribute it back if it is good.

Comment: Sure, read the XEP, read the Smack source, especially how other extensions are implemented. Start with an easy one, like the ping implementation and then continue reading the more complex ones.

Comment: I think you misunderstand the purpose of XEP-0321. It is mainly to allow gateways subservices to manipulate the relevant part of the user roster. For example, a gateway for ICQ running on the server can manipulate the roster entry for a user (after authorization) for that subset only (i.e. @icq.domain.net roster entries, not @domain.net).

This is NOT a generic specification for manipulating the whole user roster, especially not as another user.